# Send data with PutExtra when clicking back button

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have the following problem.

- Activity 1: Where do I send a user ID by PutExtra.
- Activity 2: Get the data with GetExtra.
- At some point in Activity 2 I send to Activity 3, sending is done again with PutExtra.

I want to go back to activity 2, sending the data as PutExtra. But in activity 2 you already have a GetExtra that expects the data from activity 1, so it is giving an error. How can I send this data from Activity 3 to Activity 2 and not conflict with Activity 2 because I already expect data with GetExtra from Activity 1.

Note: The data sent is always the same. It is always the user ID that is sent as PutExtra and also received as GetExtra.

**EDIT:**

Code sending or given from Activity 2 to Activity 3

```
    public class PerfilEmpTab2 extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mCardServicoList;

    private String mId_Empresa = null;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseServicos;

    private boolean mProcessAddServico = false;


    public PerfilEmpTab2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil_emp_tab2, container, false);

        /*  Recebe id de outra tela*/
        mId_Empresa = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_empresa");

        mDatabaseServicos = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Produtos_Empresas").child(mId_Empresa);

        /*Recuperar REcyclerView*/
        mCardServicoList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardListaServicos);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        //mCardCategList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mCardServicoList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        /*Fim Recycler View*/

        loadServicos();


        return view;
    }

    private void loadServicos() {

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CardServico_row, CardServicosViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CardServico_row, CardServicosViewHolder>(

                CardServico_row.class,
                R.layout.card_servicos_row,
                CardServicosViewHolder.class,
                mDatabaseServicos

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final CardServicosViewHolder viewHolder, final CardServico_row model, int position) {

                final String servico_key = getRef(position).getKey();
                final String nome_produto = model.getNome_produto();
                final String duracao = model.getDuracao();
                final String valor = model.getValor();
                final String valorOld = model.getValorOld();


                viewHolder.setNome_produto(model.getNome_produto());
                viewHolder.setDuracao(model.getDuracao());
                viewHolder.setValor(model.getValor());
                viewHolder.setValorOld(model.getValorOld());


                /*Clique na view*/
                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent intentServicoDetalhes = new Intent(getActivity(), ServicoDetalhes.class);
                        intentServicoDetalhes.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        intentServicoDetalhes.putExtra("id_empresa", mId_Empresa);
                        startActivity(intentServicoDetalhes);

                    }
                });


                viewHolder.mAddBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //Toast.makeText(Categorias.this, nome + post_key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        CharSequence opcoes[] = new CharSequence[] {"Editar Serviço", "Ver Detalhes"};

                        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        //builder.setTitle("Opçoes");
                        //builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.setItems(opcoes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // the user clicked on colors[which]

                                switch (which) {
                                    case 0:
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(), "Dados" + "-" + servico_key + "-" + nome_produto + "-" + duracao + "-"  + valor + "-" + valorOld, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        /*Intent criarSubC = new Intent(Categorias.this, CadastroSubCategorias.class);
                                        criarSubC.putExtra("id_categ", post_key);
                                        startActivity(criarSubC);*/
                                        mProcessAddServico = false;
                                        break;
                                    case 1:
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(), "Dados" + "-" + servico_key + "-" + nome_produto + "-" + duracao + "-"  + valor + "-" + valorOld, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        mProcessAddServico = false;
                                        break;
                                }


                            }

                        });
                        builder.show();

                    }
                });

            }
        };
        mCardServicoList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


    }




    public static class CardServicosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;

    ImageButton mAddBtn;

    public CardServicosViewHolder (View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

        mAddBtn = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.addServico_tab2);

    }


    public void setNome_produto(String nome_produto){

        TextView card_nomeProduto = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvNomeProduto);
        card_nomeProduto.setText(nome_produto);

    }

    public void setDuracao(String duracao){

        TextView card_duracao = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvDuracao);
        card_duracao.setText(duracao);

    }

    public void setValor(String valor){

        TextView card_valor = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvValor);
        card_valor.setText(valor);

    }

    public void setValorOld(final String valorOld){

        if ( valorOld != null ){


            TextView card_valorOld = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvValorOld);
            card_valorOld.setText(valorOld);
            card_valorOld.setPaintFlags(card_valorOld.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG); // Risca o texto
            //card_valorOld.setPaintFlags(card_valorOld.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG)); // Remove o Risca o texto

        } else {

            TextView card_valorOld = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvValorOld);
            card_valorOld.setText(valorOld);
            card_valorOld.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }



    }

}
}
```

In Activity 3 I get:

```
mId_Empresa = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_empresa");
```

Answer (score 3):

When you start activity 3 call `startActivityForResult(intent, code)` instead of `startActivity(intint)`. Then in Activity 3 override `finish()` and call `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data)` where data is an object that you have created `new Intent()` and called putExtra `data.putExtra(key, value)` on as you want. Then in Activity 2 override `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` to handle it. `requestCode` is the code you started the activity with. Be aware that `onActivityResult` occurs before `onResume` so attempting to update the UI from `onActivityResult` might not work as expected eg notifying an adapter.

Refer to this doc for more info
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

**EDIT: added code example**

Starting activity 3 from activity 2:

```
static final int SERVICO_DETALHES_REQUEST = 1;  // The request code

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
{
    Intent intentServicoDetalhes = new Intent(getActivity(), ServicoDetalhes.class);
    intentServicoDetalhes.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intentServicoDetalhes.putExtra("id_empresa", mId_Empresa);
    startActivityForResult(intentServicoDetalhes, SERVICO_DETALHES_REQUEST );
}
```

Setting the result from activity 3:

```
@Override    
public void finish() 
{
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("id_empresa", "new_id");
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
    super.finish();
}
```

Handling the result from activity 2:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (requestCode == SERVICO_DETALHES_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        String newId = data.getStringExtra("id_empresa");
}
```

Comment: I understand. What would be the best practice in these cases, where you need to send and receive data between Activities? @Dom

Comment: This is the best practice passing data between activities. Passing it via the starting intent and returning results via the result intent @TiagoIB

Comment: This seems very complex to me.I have just passed the data with putExtra and getting as GetExtra. Would you like to show me an example of your idea? @Dom

Comment: I edited my question. I put it as I move from one activity to another. @Dom

Comment: "Then in Activity 3 override finish()..." You should not **override** `finish()`. Instead you should **call** `setResult()` and `finish()` from an appropriate event handler.

Comment: @TiagoIB have a look at my edited answer and let me know if that helps

Comment: the OnClick code refers to activity 3? Sending data to activity 2? Because this code is in my activity 2. ServicoDetalhes is activity 3. @Dom

Comment: No the OnClick code is starting activity 3, same as in your question. The difference is that it calls `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`. This means you can receive data back from activity 3.

Comment: startActivityForResult(intentServicoDetalhes, SERVICO_DETALHES_REQUEST ); Is this for me to start Activity 2, returning from Activity 3?

Comment: No, you don't start activity 2 from activity 3 at all. That is Activity 2 starting activity 3.

Comment: I updated the Activity 2 code, please check if it will work anyway. Please @Dom

Comment: @TiagoIB you need to change `startActivity(intentServicoDetalhes);` to `startActivityForResult(intentServicoDetalhes, SERVICO_DETALHES_REQUEST);` and override `onActivityResult`. Please follow the examples in my answer.